# When the computer is suspended, would it be safe to move it around now?

Tags: laptop

Since moving a laptop when it's powered on can harm the HDD, so I choose to suspend it to memory before moving, so would this still harm the computer ?

Comment: Most laptops have sensors that make moving a laptop safe.  I see no reason you shouldn't move your laptop, its design to be moved around, just take care in doing so.  Besides at least with recent windows, when its suspended is entirely in memory, the hdd is placed in a low power mode.

Comment: @Ramhound hmm, I think only Thinkpad has hdaps that would suspend disk when sensor detects a shock, are we talking about the same sensor ?

Comment: As an aside, I move my laptop around while it's fully on all the time, so it's safer than you think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't. The reason it is not a good idea to move them is because the read/write head on the hard drive could come into contact with the platter. (Supposedly) While it is suspended the read/write head should be in it's "home" position which prevents it from coming into contact with the platter.

Just don't drop it. that can break all kinds of things.

Answer (score 4):

There is a very simple answer to this question: Is the HDD spinning (and the head unparked).

If it is spinning/active it is not safe.
In suspect the drive should be off and moving it would be safe.

Comment: That raises the question: if it is not spinning, is it safe to assume the head is parked?

Comment: On modern drives. Yes.  All I ever bothered to check have autopark.  On old (20-40MB MFM or RLL) drives, no. They needed a dedicated command to park the heads.